# Disable SMS in Android

Tags: android, sms

I'd like to include a feature in my application that would include a running background service that would disable SMS, if certain conditions were met (location for instance).
Is there a way I can intercept the user wanting to open any SMS app and block it? Would a Broadcast Receiver be able to do the trick?

Maybe a different way to go about this?
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: No, there is no way you can stop a user from opening an Application, that would lead to a terrible user experience.

Comment: There seem to be applications around that do just that though (http://www.textecution.com/index.php for instance). Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do this. I think like the user before states it can't be done.