# Android service which watch if messaging app is started

Tags: android, service, sms, block, watchdog

im beginner in programming for andorid.

i would like design app which will be started with and also before default android messaging app - it should be working as sms lock app. so i think i must create service which recognises start of messaging app and runs my own application. How should be look code of this service?

and my other question is: can i control defaul messaging app from my application? i need only force start or not start messaging app after closing my application.

Excuse me my poor english and thank you for your valuable advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app out there called Textecution that performs a similar function. While that example makes it seem possible I have not found any means of stopping an app from launching.

I referenced the following related questions:

[Android : block text messaging while driving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069746/android-block-text-messaging-while-driving)

[Disable SMS in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116474/disable-sms-in-android)

[How to prevent "sms sending"/texting on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293132/how-to-prevent-sms-sending-texting-on-android)

[How programmaticaly replace internal mechanism for SMS sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174246/how-programmaticaly-replace-internal-mechanism-for-sms-sending)